# CSS not taking effect on button actions

Tags: css

I would like to control the css (look) of a button via javascript. I would like the button to have a hover over style, and also a clicked state, where the button is essentially disabled. I have created a test page, where I can toggle between the enabled and disabled states of the button, via another button. The problem is - I do not see my changes taking effect, ie the color changing appropriately etc.
Here is the code:

```js
function myButtonOnClick(){
 alert("You are clickin on me!!");
  document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
}

function toggleButtonClick(){
 document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !document.getElementById("myButton").disabled;
}
```

```css
.myButton {
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
opacity: 0.86;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
/*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.myButton.hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}

.myButton.disabled {
 background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton" class="myButton" 
  onclick="myButtonOnClick()"
  value="Click Me!"></input>
  
  <input type="button" name="toggleButton" id="toggleButton" class="toggleButton"
    onclick="toggleButtonClick()"
    value="Toggle the other button"></input>
```

Comment: it's `.myButton:hover` and `.mybutton[disabled="true"]`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the disabled wrong. Its not a class, its an attribute.
Hover is also not a class.

Change

```
.myButton.hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}
.myButton.disabled {
    background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

to

```
.myButton:hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}
.myButton[disabled] {
    background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

and it should work.

I recommend that you read more about how selectors work in CSS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to change the hover style is item: and not item. (which stand for class)

```js
function myButtonOnClick(){
 alert("You are clickin on me!!");
  document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
}

function toggleButtonClick(){
 document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !document.getElementById("myButton").disabled;
}
```

```css
.myButton {
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
opacity: 0.86;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
/*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.myButton:hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}

.myButton:disabled {
 background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton" class="myButton" 
  onclick="myButtonOnClick()"
  value="Click Me!"></input>
  
  <input type="button" name="toggleButton" id="toggleButton" class="toggleButton"
    onclick="toggleButtonClick()"
    value="Toggle the other button"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your style like this...

```css
.myButton {
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
opacity: 0.86;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
/*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.myButton:hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}

.myButton:disabled {
 background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put a wrong code of you css thats why not affecting the design, You are using `.myButton.disabled` the correct using of that are `.myButton:disabled`

```js
function myButtonOnClick(){
 alert("You are clickin on me!!");
  document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
}

function toggleButtonClick(){
 document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !document.getElementById("myButton").disabled;
}
```

```css
.myButton {
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
opacity: 0.86;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
/*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.myButton:hover {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  background-color: pink;
}

.myButton:disabled {
 background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton" class="myButton" 
  onclick="myButtonOnClick()"
  value="Click Me!"></input>
  
  <input type="button" name="toggleButton" id="toggleButton" class="toggleButton"
    onclick="toggleButtonClick()"
    value="Toggle the other button"></input>
```